# APNS not working Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have two **.mobileprovision** files, both with push notification enabled.

I recently updated to **Xcode 9 with Base SDK 11.0.**

One **.mobileprovision** works fine but when I use the other .mobileprovision, it shows error symbol(red ! mark) beside "Add the Push Notification feature to your App ID" under Capabilities.

Many solutions tell to restart Xcode or clean the project. Nothing works.

What do I do?

Comment: Try deleting the provisioning profile, and download it afresh from Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> <Your Apple Developer Account> -> Download Manual Profiles. Or download directly from developer.apple.com and double-click to install it.

Comment: How do I delete the provisioning profile from Xcode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686725/543101

Comment: @VidyaMurthy No change. The problem still exists.

Comment: Are both the provisioning profiles for Development? If yes, why do you need two?